# Difference between importing module as const and var in node.js

Tags: node.js, declaration, require, node-modules

I am using a mqtt client for node.js

On this link https://blog.risingstack.com/getting-started-with-nodejs-and-mqtt/, mqtt module is imported like this;

```
const mqtt = require('mqtt')  
const client = mqtt.connect('mqtt://broker.hivemq.com')
```

The way I do my module import is like this;

```
var mqtt = require('mqtt')  
var client = mqtt.connect('mqtt://broker.hivemq.com')
```

What is the difference between the 2 ways, var and const? What if I do the import this way;

```
let mqtt = require('mqtt')  
let client = mqtt.connect('mqtt://broker.hivemq.com')
```

Does it matter? Which is the correct programming way?

I am using node.js v6

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Regardless of whether you're using it for a `require` or not, `const` means the variable cannot be reassigned, while `let` allows it to be reassigned.  Both `let` and `const` are block scoped, while `var` is function scoped.  Generally, most folks using ES6-compatible things (which node v6 is mostly ES6 compatible) suggest to prefer `const` and `let` and never (or rarely) use `var`.  This tends to provide the scoping behavior that most folks expect, especially if coming from another language.

In the case of your `require` statements, I can't think of a case where you'd ever want to reassign those variables, so `const` should be the preferred method.

Comment: what about using import, like so: import chalk = require('chalk');

Comment: I've never seen that syntax before @ramon22.  I've only seen `import chalk from 'chalk'`.